# What is use of button description in Microsoft Fabric UI?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

There is button description span in Microsoft Fabric button. What is the use of it? When that span is really used, I was expecting it will show tooltip but it doesn't show.

```xml
<button class="ms-Button buttonsInGroup" id="selectTimespan">
    <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Select Timespan</span>
    <span class="ms-Button-description">Modify the selected range for tags.</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [Office Dev Center](http://dev.office.com/fabric/components/button) you can see an example for the compound button for which it is rendered below. For the other buttons I guess the main function could be for accessibility reasons like screen readers.

[image: Compound button]